# Convert Tsql query result from rows to column names with other rows as column data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use this query to get result :

```
Declare @Mag Int = 237006
;With Res
As
(
  Select
    Mnf.FileTypeID As MagType,
    Mnf.InsertDate As MagDate,
    Mnf.Star,
    Nl.LogType,
    Nl.InsertDate As LogDate
  From 
    MagazineNumberFiles As Mnf
    Left Outer Join Nomags_Log As Nl On Nl.MagazineNumberID = Mnf.MagazineNumberID
  Where 
    Mnf.MagazineNumberID = @Mag
)
Select * From Res
```

Result of this query is:

```
MagType MagDate         Star    LogType LogDate
2           2013-04-13  *       7       2013-04-16 
6           2013-04-14  *       3       2013-04-17 
8           2013-04-15  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I want convert this result to  :

```
MagType2    MagStar2 MagType6   MagStar6 MagType8 MagStar8 LogType7     LogType3
2013-04-13  *        2013-04-14 *        5        NULL     2013-04-16   2013-04-17
```

How can I do this using tsql ?

Comment: Where does MagType8 of 5 come from? Should it be 2013-04-15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, with some ugly dynamic sql:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

select @sql = 'select ' + stuff((select
',''' + convert(varchar,MagDate) + ''' as MagType' + convert(varchar,MagType)
+ char(10)
+ isnull(',''' + convert(varchar,Star) + '''', ',null') + ' as MagStar' 
+ convert(varchar,MagType)
+ char(10)
+ isnull(',''' + convert(varchar,LogDate) + ''' as LogType', '') 
+ isnull(convert(varchar,LogType), '')
+ char(10)
from Res
for xml path(''))
,1,1,'');

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```